# ¿Como hacer para cambiar el nombre de titulo en la toolbar? ¿y como hago para centrarlo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar

Me gustaría saber como hacer para cambiarle el titulo de cada actividad (Tengo ocho actividades diferentes) en la toolbar.

Yo tengo creado un **toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:popupTheme="@style/Popup">
```

donde utilizo include

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

en cada xml de la actividad donde quiero utilizar mi toolbar.

Después también como hacer para centrar ese titulo. Por favor es urgente.

**Gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Hola, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Deseas que cada actividad tenga su titulo respectivo en la toolbar ? si es así solo debes agregar el nombre en manisfets a cada XML

Comment: Hola Ashley G si eso ya lo probé. Pero como hago para centrar ese título desde el manifest?

Comment: Ya modificaste tu archivo styles.xml a NoActionBar para poder personalizar tu Toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega directamente el titulo en el `Toolbar` mediante la propiedad

```
app:title="titulo toolbar"
```

por ejemplo:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:title="titulo toolbar"/>
```

o programaticamente:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("titulo toolbar");
```

---

**Actualización:**

Desde los layouts de tus Activity estas cargando un `include` el cual tiene definido un `Toolbar`:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

#### Centrar Texto en Toolbar:

Si deseas centrar el texto dentro de tu `Toolbar` lo podrías realizar agregando un `TextView` dentro de tu `Toolbar`, y define la propiedad `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:elevation="4dp"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     app:popupTheme="@style/Popup">

            <TextView            

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="titulo Toolbar!!!"
                android:gravity = "center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[Aquí una respuesta similar en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

#### Cambiar texto en Toolbar:

Para cambiar el texto busca la referencia del `TextView` y cambia el texto mediante el método `setText()`

```
TextView titleToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
titleToolbar.setText("titulo toolbar");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS GRANDE!!!!!

Comment: Excelente @user9524937 , recuerda que es importante agregar detalles y ser específicos a la hora de preguntar eso ayudara a que tengas varias respuestas que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Gracias, esta fue mi primera pregunta! Muchísimas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hago para centrar el titulo en los toolbars es lo siguiente

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"   //esta es la linea importante
            android:text="TU_TITULO" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Lo que hago es agregar un `textview` dentro del `toolbar` y ese `textview` con la propiedad `layout_gravity`, centrarlo. 
Luego en tu caso, si lo tienes en un include, puedes acceder a el de manera programatica de la siguiente forma

```
TextView tituloToolbar = findViewById(R.id.textView_toolbar)
tituloToolbar.setText("aca el titulo de tu activity nuevo");
```